# Why 'the electric current is “shorted out” by the conductor' in Stutzman-Thiele Antenna Theory and Design?

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

Page 346, in Stutzman-Thiele Antenna Theory and Design-3d edition, reads 'the electric current is “shorted out” by the conductor' and is thus nullified. Refer to part c of the image below:

[image]

In this page, with this sentence (as I understand), the authors are trying to explain Love's equivalence principle in the context of aperture antennas. With this principle, one can find the radiation fields of an antenna structure (enclosed by the closed surface S) if he knows the equivalent electric and magnetic currents on the surface of the antenna when it is difficult to find the actual sources and currents inside S. The formula for these currents, for the general problem in part b is according to the authors in the same page :

[image]

Next, the authors,using the general problem in (b), arrive at the special equivalent problem in (c) where E1, and H1 are zero and introduce material inside S, in particular a perfect electric conductor which does not alter the problem. The explanation follows:

[image]

[image]

So it appears that a closed perfect electric conductor cannot sustain a current on the surface. Is this reasoning true?

Comment: I apologize, I do not have *"Stutzman-Thiele Antenna Theory and Design-3d edition"* available so I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Yeah, please give, way, way more context. Someone who's not sitting in your chair needs to understand what you're talking about!

Comment: how about showing some useful diagrams, and explain which currents are bucking each other?

Comment: Included some diagrams. Actually the page in question.

Comment: please crop them so that they become *useful*.

Comment: if you have a changing electric field, expect a displacement current on surface of the conductor.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Could you elaborate on that? How does this explain the cancelling of Js? Js is a 'real' conduction current.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly: No, that is not true.

A perfect electric conductor(PEC) *can* sustain a current on the surface, in fact, it is very good at doing this since it is perfectly conducting! The reason you can ignore \$J_s\$ in this case is because a current density can not *radiate* on a PEC. Think of it in terms of image theory, the tangential electric field produced by \$J_s\$ will be canceled out by its image producing an opposite electric field, see Figure 1. So for our purposes of solving for the radiated fields \$E\$ and \$H\$, \$J_s\$ can be ignored (ie. \$J_s\$ = 0). However, you can also see that a magnetic current density \$M_s\$ producing a tangential magnetic field would essentially be *doubled* on a PEC rather than canceled! From electromagnetic uniqueness concepts we know that we only need \$M_s\$ (or\$J_s\$) to solve for both the magnetic and electric fields. Therefore we use our *a priori* knolwedge of the tangential fields over the surface \$S\$ (remember we didnt know the *sources* within, but we did have to know the tangential fields on \$S\$) and solve for \$M_s\$ using:
$$
M_s = E\times \hat{n}
$$

For a simple geometry such as a flat PEC as previously discussed we get simply:
$$
M_s = 2E\times \hat{n}
$$

See Figure 2.

This also fits very well with a simple case of an open waveguide propagating a TE mode since you have known tangential electric fields and presumably a large conducting flange around the mouth of the waveguide. You can carry out this same procedure, see Figure 3.

[image: Figure 1 - Image Theory PEC]

Figure 1 - Image Theory PEC

[image: Figure 2 - Equivalent Magnetic Current on PEC]

Figure 2 - Equivalent Magnetic Current on PEC

[image: Figure 3 - Equivalence Applied to Waveguide]

Figure 3 - Equivalence Applied to Waveguide

Comment: Yes, I know that a current on the closed surface of a PEC cannot radiate and guessed that this is what the authors would like to communicate. But then I thought this is Stutzman and Thiele. Two such highly renowned authors can't possibly make a mistake like this.

Comment: @nikoschatziathanasiou I do find their word choice confusing. I learned from Balanis's Antenna Theory book (taught directly by him) and it wasnt worded quite that way.

Comment: Ok. Back to the actual electromagnetics. How would a conducting wire react when radiation with the electric field parallel to the wire impinges upon it? I guess it would reflect some portion of the incoming radiation. This reflection has to be due to current induced on the wire. How is this reflection explained in the context of the question in hand?

Comment: @nikoschatziathanasiou Well the context of the problem at hand assumes we are using an equivalency, where we really do have a nonzero E field at the boundary but we assume a PEC and solve for the surface current Js. In the case of a wire with an incident wave the boundary condition is that the tangential E field must be zero at the surface of the wire. Therefore the tangential component of the reflected field must be such that it cancels the tangential component of the incident field. But yes, there is an induced current that re-radiates the reflected field.